# How to hide fields for unauthenticated users with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I know that to hide columns, we can use the `protected $hidden` attribute, however it will hide for everyone who will request the data.

For example, I have route / faq / index, a table / model with questions and answers (FAQ) and want to hide the `updated_by` and `created_by` fields so that non-authenticated users can see, does Laravel have any resource for this type of situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Eloquent Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources). Then you can conditionally return attributes like this:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
  return [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'name' => $this->name,
    'email' => $this->email,
    'secret' => $this->when(Auth::check(), 'secret-value'), // this field will only be visible when the users is authed
  ];
}
```

You can also group the hidden attributes:

```
 $this->mergeWhen(Auth::check(), [
    'first-secret' => 'value',
    'second-secret' => 'value',
 ]),
```

Read about conditional attributes [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources#conditional-attributes).

Comment: It worked, but since I was using a route that does not have the auth:api (dingo) middleware, so I had to use this $request->user('api') method, inside the when instead of Auth::check, thank you!